# Dynamic Values in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to configure GTM for my website. I am able to configure most of the tags in GTM, but facing issues while creating tags and triggers for values that generate at run time. For ex:

data-category="${item.linkTitle}" href="${item.externalizedLinkPath}">${item.linkTitle}

Not able to add anchor tag, but it is visible in Image.
[DOM Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oqdv.png)

@VictorLeontyev : Please check the DOM markup in below image. Let me know, if anymore information is required.

[DOM Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nPkk.png)

Example values: **data-category="store" data-label="top_menu" ,
data-category="support" data-label="top_menu"**

And values "support" , "store" will be authored at run time by author

Here, ${item.linkTitle} will be a dynamic value, which will generate at run time, and can be having 5 values. I need to create 5 tags on this DOM according to the runtime value it gets.

I am not able to do it. Please, let me know, what I need to do ?

Thanks in Advance,
Harshit

Comment: Are you able to edit the `<a>` tag? If so, can you attach an ID to it and pick it up that way?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of your dome with more markup, at least it will give us understanding how it's dynamically populated and how to build  proper trigger for GTM

Comment: @vinoaj : I can edit the anchor tag and can add id attribute there, and then retrieve using it, but will it work for my GTM tags, because for the same anchor tag i need to create 5 tags, which will get value on run time. How ID will help ? Please see the attached image also, in below comment

Comment: @VictorLeontyev : Here is the screenshot of dom with more markup. I added two different markups, but the requirement is same. Both needs to pick the value of title in data-attribute, as i highlighted in DOM. Please see the image (DOM Image 2) below in new comment.

Comment: @vinoaj: Using unique ID method also, tags are not working. Can you suggest some another method ?

Comment: To further troubleshoot it would be helpful if you can show us (a) the HTML including where the dataLayer is and where the GTM snippet is and (b) the configuration of your tags, triggers, and variables

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggested solution provided that you can modify the `<a>` tags.

1. Modify `<a>` tags to have a class name or unique IDs Create a
   *Trigger* (we'll call it *T1*) that fires after the data in your `<a>` tags have resolved (possibly on `DOMContentLoaded`)
2. Write a
   *Custom HTML* tag (we'll call it *CH1*) to loop through the `<a>` tags, extract the attribute data, and push the data to the
   `dataLayer` along with an event (e.g. `event: 'dataLoaded')

   2. This tag
      will be triggered by *T1*
3. Then you do whatever you need to do with
   the data by creating a tag that is triggered by the `dataLoaded`
   event